Extruding geometry between two points - ThreeJS
I have been looking for hours on how to do this but I can't seem to figure this one out.
What I want to do is just to extrude a shape between two Vector3 points in ThreeJS. I tried this code below, but it just extrudes from the start point then to the global Z-axis. The face shape is also parallel to the XY plane.
What I'm trying to do is create a shape with its plane perpendicular to the line connecting the startPt and endPt. And its length is within the startPt and endPt.
export function Create3DWSection(wSection: WSection, startPt: THREE.Vector3, endPt: THREE.Vector3, scene: THREE.Scene) {

  const square = new THREE.Shape();

  const width: number = 0.5;
  const height: number = 0.5;

  square.moveTo(startPt.x + width / 2, startPt.y + height / 2);
  square.lineTo(startPt.x - width / 2, startPt.y + height / 2);
  square.lineTo(startPt.x - width / 2, startPt.y -height / 2);
  square.lineTo(startPt.x + width / 2, startPt.y -height / 2);

  let dir = new THREE.Vector3();

  const memberLength: number = startPt.distanceTo(endPt);

  const extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 1,
    depth: memberLength,
    bevelEnabled: false,
  };

  const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(square, extrudeSettings);
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);
}

Thank you very much for your help!
